# Scrape all years and issues of journal with nested for loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping

I managed to scrape headlines and body text for all issues in one year of an old German journal called `Gartenlaube`

- This is one year: https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Die_Gartenlaube_(1853)
- This is one issue: https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Die_Gartenlaube_(1853)/Heft_1

Here is a dataframe of all years and the number of issues (almost always weekly, but not completely).

```
structure(list(Year = c(1853, 1854, 1855, 1856, 1857, 1858, 1859, 
1860, 1861, 1862, 1863, 1864, 1865, 1866, 1867, 1868, 1869, 1870, 
1871, 1872, 1873, 1874, 1875, 1876, 1877, 1878, 1879, 1880, 1881, 
1882, 1883, 1884, 1885, 1886, 1887, 1888, 1889, 1890, 1891, 1892, 
1893, 1894, 1895, 1896, 1897, 1898, 1899), count = c(52L, 52L, 
52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 49L, 52L, 52L, 51L, 52L, 
52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 
53L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 52L, 52L, 28L, 52L, 28L, 52L, 
52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 28L, 28L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -47L))
```

I can download all issues for one year like this:

```
data <- list()

for(i in 1:52){ 
  url <- paste0("https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Die_Gartenlaube_(1853)/Heft_", i)
  html_document  <- rvest::read_html(url)
  
  html_document %>%
    html_nodes("h2") %>%
    html_text() -> title
  title <- title[-1]
  
  text <- character()
  
  for(j in 1:(length(title)-2)){
    # store text between first and next title
    html_document %>%
      html_nodes(xpath = paste0("//p[preceding-sibling::h2[. = '", 
                                title[j], 
                                "'] and following-sibling::h2[. = '",
                                title[j+1], "']]")) %>%
      html_text() -> txt
    # collapse text vector
    text[j] <- paste0(txt, sep="",collapse = '')
    j <- j+1
  }
  
  # bind data
  n <- max(length(title), length(text))
  length(title) <- n                      
  length(text) <- n
  
  data[[i]] <- cbind(title, text)
} 

# rbind
GL1853_head_text = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, data))

# Create list of issues
issues <- list()

for(i in 1:52){
  issues[[i]] <- rep(i, nrow(as.data.frame(data[[i]])))
}

GL1853_head_text$issue <- unlist(issues)
GL1853_head_text$year <- 1853
```

Here is the data of year 1853

```
as_tibble(GL1983_head_text)

# A tibble: 312 × 4
   title                                   text                                                                                     issue  year
   <chr>                                   <chr>                                                                                    <int> <dbl>
 1 An unsere Freunde und Leser!            "Grüß Euch Gott, lieben Leute im deutschen Lande!\nZu den vielen Geschenken, die Euch d…     1  1853
 2 Ein Mutterherz.                         "In einem jener stillen grünen Thäler des schönen Sachsenlandes, wo lieblich die blauen…     1  1853
 3 Der Deutsche in Amerika.                "Es war ein schöner Sonntagsmorgen, als ich von Dir und der Heimath Abschied nahm. Auf …     1  1853
 4 Aus der Menschenheimath.                "Da ist sie nun wieder, die Zeit der Weihnacht und des Jahreswechsels. Da freut sich Al…     1  1853
 5 Anmerkungen (Wikisource)                 NA                                                                                          1  1853
 6 Navigationsmenü                          NA                                                                                          1  1853
 7 Ein Mutterherz.                         "Dem prachtvollen Frühlingsmorgen folgte ein wonniger Maientag. Felicitas, welcher der …     2  1853
 8 Ein Quartier des Elends und der Arbeit. "Mann des Ostens, der du einmal herüber gekommen bist aus den freundlichen Städten läng…     2  1853
 9 Aus der Menschenheimath.                "Hast Du Dir schon einmal das Samenkorn einer Pappel angesehen? Wahrscheinlich nicht. E…     2  1853
10 Blätter und Blüthen                     "Wie wir hören, baut jetzt ein Leipziger Techniker an einem lenkbaren Luftschiff, desse…     2  1853
# … with 302 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I failed to build another `for` loop around this to repeat this procedure for years. I also failed to build a non-loop solution, something vectorized. I would opt for any working solution that yields a dataframe of year-issue-title-text data.

Comment: What did your `for` loop and non-loop attempts look like? How exactly did they fail? It's easier to help you fix your solution than ask someone else to solve your problem from scratch.

Comment: Sure, one problem is how I store the intermediate results, I think in a list of lists? So I tried, 3 nested for loops, years, issues and titles/headings. I'll update the code. The last problem is to unlist this list of lists in a tidy dataframe.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/MarcoKuehne/27afe2b8b887f1ee279ecb5cf6b588c3 Here is a trial with the nested loop structure.